# How do I execute a command but only add a *modified* version of it to the history?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, command-history

I'm trying to create an analog of the command history, but for the *output* of the commands, so that I can do e.g. `locate filename` (which might display *several* files) and then `vim %2` (or whatever) to edit the second one.

So far I have:

```zsh
my-ret() {
    print -n " : `date +%s` : " >>~/.zsh-output
    BUFFER+=" >&1 >>~/.zsh-output"
    zle accept-line
}
zle -N my-ret
bindkey '\e\r' my-ret
```

But this adds e.g. `ls -l >&1 >>~/.zsh-output` to my command history.

I've found `print -s` which I could use to add the original `$BUFFER` to the command history. But won't executing the modified line also add that to the history?

I suppose I want something that executes a command, but doesn't add it to the history.

Comment: Have you considered using your terminal emulators completion based on what's on the screen like [xterm's dabbrev feature](https://x.org/releases/X11R6.8.2/doc/xterm.1.html#sect11).

Comment: See also `print -Pn '%D{%s}'` or `print -n $EPOCHSECONDS` (needs `zmodload zsh/datetime`) to print the epoch time

Comment: I'm using macOS Terminal (might switch to iTerm2). That has cmd-F for finding text. I don't think it has an exact equivalent of dabbrev, but that's not exactly what I'm after anyway. -- I've also just started playing with ```tmux``` which can capture all the output, without having to modify the command.